# JUnit5 properties file causes unwanted logging during test runs

Tags: junit5

I have set the default test lifecycle to `per_class` for a project using JUnit5. This is done in the `junit-platform.properties` file. However, since applying this configuration, my test runs are now preceded by a lot of logging output:

```
Dec 06, 2018 8:15:22 PM org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherConfigurationParameters fromClasspathResource
INFO: Loading JUnit Platform configuration parameters from classpath resource [file:/Users/amb85/Projects/kotlin/katas/out/test/resources/junit-platform.properties].
Dec 06, 2018 8:15:22 PM org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestInstanceLifecycleUtils getDefaultTestInstanceLifecycle
INFO: Using default test instance lifecycle mode 'PER_CLASS' set via the 'junit.jupiter.testinstance.lifecycle.default' configuration parameter.
```

I don't want to see these log messages. How do I disable them or set the log level higher?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I know it was a while ago... so....

Comment: No, not that I remember. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Found an answer in:
https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1774#issuecomment-463662553

Summarizing:
Set 'java.util.logging.config.file' system property pointing to a logging.properties file that reduces the log level.

```
 tasks.withType(Test).configureEach {
  useJUnitPlatform()

  systemProperty 'java.util.logging.config.file', "${project.buildDir}/resources/test/logging-test.properties"

  testLogging {
    showStandardStreams = true
  }
}
```

logging-test.properties:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=INFO

org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherConfigurationParameters.level=WARNING
org.junit.jupiter.engine.config.EnumConfigurationParameterConverter.level=WARNING
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also having the same issue. A possible solution may be to intercept the default JUnit5 logger (java.util.logging.LogManager) and discard that INFO log. I have not yet implemented it, but you are not alone with this.

Here's some links from my research:

- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle-changing-default
- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-interfaces-and-default-methods